# Ajuda com Async C# / WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium-webdriver, async

bom dia!

Montei um pequeno projeto para estudo onde eu coleto dados de um site e jogo para um DataGridView usando o Selenium.
Tenho 3 Classes

> Robot.cs -> Onde tenho o métodos de navegação e coleta de dados.

```
//NAVEGAR PARA O SITE(URL)
public void GoToUrl(string Url)
{
    RoboDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);
}
//PROCURAR POR XPATH LER E RETORNAR VALOR
public string ReadByXPath(string XPath, string attribute)
{
    string SetRead;
    Wait.Until(d => RoboDriver.FindElementByXPath(XPath));
    SetRead = RoboDriver.FindElementByXPath(XPath).GetAttribute(attribute);
    return SetRead;
}
```

> RobotNavigation.cs -> Responsável pela navegação.

```
        //METODO PARA BUSCAR E PREENCHER AS COTAÇÕES DO DATAGRIDVIEW
    public void GetQuotes(DataGridView dataGridView, ProgressBar progressBar)
    {
        //ZERAR BARRA DE PROGRESSO
        progressBar.Value = 0;
        //DEFININDO VALOR DA BARRA DE PROGRESSO
        progressBar.Maximum = dataGridView.RowCount;
        //PERCORRER REGISTROS DO DATAGRIDVIEW
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            //TRAVAR DATAGRIDVIEW
            dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            string codActive = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            //MONTAR URL DE NAVEGAÇÃO COM CÓDIGO OBTIDO
            string url = "https://www.fundamentus.com.br/detalhes.php?papel=" + codActive;
            //NAVEGAR PARA SITE (URL)
            GoToUrl(url);
            //PREENCHER COLUNA DO DATAGRIDVIEW COM A COTAÇÃO OBTIDA NO SITE
            row.Cells[1].Value = ReadByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/span", "innerHTML");
            //INCREMENTAR BARRA DE PROGRESSO
            progressBar.PerformStep();
        }
        //FECHAR ROBO
        RobotQuit();
        //HABILITAR DATAGRIDVIEW
        dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
    }
}
```

> Form1.cs -> Onde executo a navegação através de um botão.

```
        private void bntPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RobotNavigation robotNavigation = new RobotNavigation();
        robotNavigation.GetQuotes(dgvMain, pBar);
    }
```

Gostaria de uma ajuda para tornar esse projeto assíncrono para que o form e os componentes não travem enquanto o robo navega, coleta dados e trabalha com os componentes passados via parâmetro.

Comment: Você deve implementar uma thread que roda a logica de coleta dos dados, assim a thread da aplicação não ficara travada até o termino da operação. Da uma olhada aqui https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem?view=netframework-3.5

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar usar uma task para rodar a lógica:

```
private async void bntPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task tks = Task.Run(() => 
    {
        RobotNavigation robotNavigation = new RobotNavigation();
        robotNavigation.GetQuotes(dgvMain, pBar);
    });

    await tks;
}
```

Comment: Olá! Bom dia! Já havia tentado isso envolvendo os componentes em um void{} e invocando usando o Invoker.... mas ñ rolou... acredito que vou ter q mudar essa estrutura pra dar certo...

Answer (score 0):

bom dia!

Acabei alterando a estrutura do projeto para obter o resultado que esperava e sendo assim fiquei somente com os arquivos Robot e Form1.

Segue repositório caso queiram ver o resultado final.

https://github.com/lbert1/Pepe-Robot

## Form1.cs

```
   public void GetQuotes()
    {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        MethodInvoker invPBarStart = delegate
        {
            //ZERAR BARRA DE PROGRESSO
            pBar.Value = 0;
            //DEFININDO VALOR DA BARRA DE PROGRESSO
            pBar.Maximum = dgvMain.RowCount;              
        };
        Invoke(invPBarStart);
        //PERCORRER REGISTROS DO DATAGRIDVIEW
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMain.Rows)
        {
            MethodInvoker invDgvStart = delegate
            {
                //TRAVAR ADICONAR NO DATAGRIDVIEW
                dgvMain.AllowUserToAddRows = false;            
            };
            Invoke(invDgvStart);
            string codActive = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            //MONTAR URL DE NAVEGAÇÃO COM CÓDIGO OBTIDO
            string url = "https://www.fundamentus.com.br/detalhes.php?papel=" + codActive;
            //NAVEGAR PARA SITE (URL)
            robot.GoToUrl(url);
            //PREENCHER COLUNA DO DATAGRIDVIEW COM A COTAÇÃO OBTIDA NO SITE
            row.Cells[1].Value = robot.ReadByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/span", "innerHTML");
            //INCREMENTAR BARRA DE PROGRESSO
            MethodInvoker invPBarStep = delegate
            {
                pBar.PerformStep();
            };
            Invoke(invPBarStep);
        }
        //FECHAR ROBO
        robot.RobotQuit();
        MethodInvoker invDgvEnd = delegate
        {            
            //HABILITAR DATAGRIDVIEW
            dgvMain.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        };
        Invoke(invDgvEnd);
    }

    private async void bntPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //CHAMAR METODO GETQUOTES DE FORMA ASSINCRONA
        await Task.Run(() => GetQuotes());
    }
```